# Perl Regex to Match Colon Occurrence if Present

Tags: regex, perl

I want to regex match any alphabet/number/underscore character as well as double colons in a string if the first word contains "Blue".

For example,

```
Blue Red Yellow //return Red
Blue Red::Orange Yellow //return Red::Orange
Purple Red Yellow //return nothing
Blue R_E_D //return R_E_D 
Red Blue //return nothing 
Blue.ish Yellow //return Yellow
```

I tried `/Blu\S+\s+(\w+)/` and it's working for all cases except the `::` case. How can I add a match after checking for `w+` to match double colons as well IF present without having to mandate my regex to only match if there is a `::` present as well.

Comment: `^Blu\S+\s(\S+)` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jhSMi9/1)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a capture group and repeat the word char or `:`

```
^Blue\b\S*\h+([\w:]+)
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Or use `\b` if not at the start
- `Blue\b\S*` Match the word `Blue` and optional non whitspace cahrs
- `\h+` Match 1+ spaces
- `([\w:]+)` Capture 1+ word chars or `:` in group 1

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WiP6oQ/1)

Or using `\K` to clear the match buffer:

```
^Blue\b\S*\h+\K[\w:]+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WOMFTy/1)

If the word can not start with a colon but should have `::` in between and `Bluebird` should also match as noted in the comments by @[ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami):

```
\bBlue\S*\h+\K\w+(?:::\w+)*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OgM28s/1)

Comment: Doesn't match `Bluebird Red`. Not sure if that matters or not, but the description suggests it should. Simply remove the `\b` if that's desired.

Comment: @ikegami Ah, in that case the `\b` can be omitted of course :-)

Comment: I am trying this but it matches single colon as well. I only want to be able to match double colons.

Comment: @programminglearner This pattern does not match a single colon `\bBlue\S*\h+\K\w+(?:::\w+)*` https://regex101.com/r/OgM28s/1 Can you give an example where there is a match for a single colon? If you don't want a partial match, the you can use `\bBlue\S*\h+\K\w+(?:::\w+)*(?!\S)` https://regex101.com/r/oGlhq4/1